# Perl converting a string into groups of 8 hex digits

Tags: perl

I am trying to take a string, let's say "asdkljasdkjlaksjdla" and:

```
1. Print it in reverse order
2. convert it to hex
3. print in groups of 8 with leading 0x
```

So for example the string "asdkljasdkjlaksjdla" should print out like

```
0x616c646a
0x736b616c
0x6a6b6473
```

and so on.

So far I have this:

```
perl -e 'print unpack "H*", scalar reverse "asdkljasdkjlaksjdla"'
```

but I have not been able to figure out how to make the groups. Can you help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the hex conversion and splitting in one step with `unpack "(H8)*"`:

```
print "0x$_\n" for unpack "(H8)*", scalar reverse "asdkljasdkjlaksjdla";
```

See [perlpacktut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html#Template-Grouping) for more information on this syntax.

(Ps. Strictly speaking, the `scalar` is unnecessary, since `unpack` already evaluates its second argument in scalar context. I'd rather have it there explicitly, though, so that the next person reading or editing this doesn't have to remember that detail. Feel free to remove it if you disagree.)

Comment: thank you very much, this does the trick :). And thank you to everyone else who responded.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -E 'my $x= unpack "H*", scalar reverse "asdkljasdkjlaksjdla" ; say "0x$_" for ( $x =~ /(.{1,8})/g ) '
```

Needed another paren, and got it without the temp:

```
perl -E 'say "0x$_" for ( ( unpack "H*", scalar reverse "asdkljasdkjlaksjdla" ) =~ /(.{1,8})/g )'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Perl 5.14.0 or later (needed for the [`/r`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) modifier to `s///`):

```
perl -e 'print ((unpack "H*", reverse "asdkljasdkjlaksjdla") =~ s/.{2,8}/0x$&\n/gr)'
```

All the spaces are optional; all the parentheses are necessary.

Output:

```
0x616c646a
0x736b616c
0x6a6b6473
0x616a6c6b
0x647361
```